# Create a nested list out of list names

Tags: r, list, merge, nested

```
list1 <- 1:3
list2 <- letters[1:3]
```

I'd like to combine them in a list but *not* by simple listing them in `list(list1, list2)`, but in a more generalized fashion.

For example, by using `ls(pattern = "^list*")`. However, that only combines the names and not the actual lists. How do you access, substitute, or refer to the actual lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for `mget`:

```
list1 <- 1:3
list2 <- letters[1:3]
mget(ls(pattern = "list\\d"))
# $list1
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# $list2
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Comment: @Rico, so is it what you're looking for or not?